# Not getting correct count on OrderID

Tags: sql-server-2008

My Sample data

```
EmailAddress   CustomerID OrderID OrderDate
XYZ@gmail.com   123454    1244     04/11/2018
XYZ@gmail.com   123466    1249     04/15/2018
```

My data is unique only by emailaddress.
I have a SQL Query where Customers,Orders and Orderdetails table are involved. I am trying to get total_ordered by customer but it is not giving me right results. But when i remove orderdetails table from my query i get count right . I am not understanding why it is happening.  I want Total_Ordered column to be calculated correctly. Right now it is doubling the purchases by a customer. Any help is appreciated.

```
SELECT
Customers.EmailAddress,
COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as Total_Ordered,
COUNT(CASE WHEN od.ProductCode LIKE 'DSC%' THEN  od.ProductCode END ) as DscoRDERS
FROM Orders 
JOIN (
      SELECT
         Orderid,
          ProductCode
      FROM OrderDetails
      GROUP BY
OrderID,
      ProductCode
) od ON Orders.Orderid = od.Orderid
JOIN Customers ON Customers.Customerid = Orders.Customerid
WHERE
Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN ' 01/01/2018 00:00' AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY
Customers.EmailAddress
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data.  I would not group by Customers.EmailAddress, should use an ID column as it may  be possible (depending on your code) to have 2 customers with same email address.

Comment: Avoid regional formats like `01/01/2018` - [much safer to use `20180101`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). Generally, [stay away from BETWEEN](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) for date range queries. Also, can an order date be in the future? If not, then just `>= '20180101'` will do.

Comment: @Brad..I Have provided the sample

Answer (score 0):

When you introduce the OrderDetails table, you're getting one row in your result set for every item on any given order. When you're counting Orders.OrderID, then, the number gets inflated when OrderDetails come in.

Try changing that line to this:

```
...
COUNT(DISTINCT Orders.OrderID) as Total_Ordered,
...
```